# Cannot append to a returned list?

Tags: python

```
def f():
    lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return lst[1:]
```

why is `f().append('a') is None == True` even though `f().__class__` is `<type 'list'>` and `f() == ['b', 'c']`

Comment: Evaluate this:  `[].append('a')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `append()` returns `None` and not the list object. Use

```
l = f()
l.append('a')
...
```

Comment: +1: This requires a #StdPython_2 kind of answer.  Methods which mutate an object (almost) never return a value.  `pop()` is the notable exception.

Answer (score 2):

Because `append()` modifies the list, but does not return it.

Answer (score 1):

In this context it's always good to be fully aware of the difference between expressions and commands. There are basically two ways to append a value `x` to a list `l`

1. Using a command: `l.append(x)`. Usually a command doesn't return any value; it performs some kind of side-effect.
2. Using an expression, namely `l+[x]` which stands for a value and does nothing. I.e. you assign `l=l+[x]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f()+['a']
```

Hope this helps